# R rCharts - a slider not appearing when x-axis values are the dates

Tags: r, plot, rcharts

I am building a rCharts object. It uses a vector of strings formatted like a **data** (*"yyyy-mm-dd"*) **as values of x-axis**. This way is taken from this rCharts 'official' [tutorial](http://ramnathv.github.io/rCharts/) (find *m1* plot code) - in both (tutorial's and mine) cases the x-axis values are of `character` type and rCharts seems to recognize it (for example it sets the x-axis visible values to *"yyyy-mm"* format when the scope is narrow enough etc.)

For my purposes, it would be absolutely great if I could use the **slider** in the x-axis, but my implementation fails to work... The slider simply does not appear at all. Below is a short R code with such not-working-with-slider plot. Any solutions?

```
library(rCharts)

set.seed(101)

dates <- c("1959-01-01", "1959-02-01", "1959-03-01", "1959-04-01", "1959-05-01", "1959-06-01",
       "1959-07-01", "1959-08-01", "1959-09-01", "1959-10-01", "1959-11-01", "1959-12-01",
       "1960-01-01", "1960-02-01", "1960-03-01", "1960-04-01", "1960-05-01", "1960-06-01",
       "1960-07-01", "1960-08-01", "1960-09-01", "1960-10-01", "1960-11-01", "1960-12-01")
data1 <- rnorm(n=24, m=1, sd=1) 
data2 <- rnorm(n=24, m=0, sd=2) 
df <- data.frame(dates, data1, data2)

plot <- mPlot(x = "dates", y = c("data1", "data2"), type = "Line", data = df)
plot$set(slider=TRUE)
plot
```

Comment: `mPlot` uses the MorrisJS library, which does not have native support for sliders built in. If you look at the examples, you will notice that the `slider` method is supported by the JS library Rickshaw.

Comment: That's the point, thank you!

Comment: If that solved your issue, I can write it up as an answer so that you can close this question. Let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer. `mPlot` uses the `MorrisJS` library, which does not have native support for sliders built in. If you look at the examples, you will notice that the slider method is supported by the JS library `Rickshaw`.